# All possible (1,2....x) letter combinations

Tags: python

I need a list all possible (1,2....x) letter combinations where x is a number.

So for 2 letter words, using list, I would do:

```
 [x+y for x in ascii_letters for y in ascii_letters]
```

for 3 letter words, I would do:

```
 [x+y+z for x in ascii_letters for y in ascii_letters for z in ascii_letters]
```

and so on.

Its clear that I am running into static repetition of code. Is there a generic way of writing this using list comprehension, map or any other method where I can supply number of letters as arguments without repeating the code.

Comment: Use `itertools`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Itertools contains most of the components you need to build this type of program. In particular, check out `itertools.product`. For example, to repeat it `n` times, do `itertools.product(thing, repeat=n)`